# Weird behavior of 'interpose' function in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I was manipulation some data and used interpose at the end. But it acted differently when it comes to some letters like **, ` ~**

**Expected behavior**

```clj
(interpose '! ["a" "b" "c"])
=> ("a" ! "b" ! "c")

(interpose 'k ["a" "b" "c"])
=> ("a" k "b" k "c")

(interpose '- ["a" "b" "c"])
=> ("a" - "b" - "c")
```

**Not Expected behavior (They return function instead of data result)**

```clj
(interpose ', ["a" "b" "c"])
=> #object[clojure.core$interpose$fn__6471 0x6f0c27f3 "clojure.core$interpose$fn__6471@6f0c27f3"]
(interpose '` ["a" "b" "c"])

=> #object[clojure.core$interpose$fn__6471 0x7b94fbcb "clojure.core$interpose$fn__6471@7b94fbcb"]
(interpose '~ ["a" "b" "c"])

=> #object[clojure.core$interpose$fn__6471 0x36966945 "clojure.core$interpose$fn__6471@36966945"]
```

Comment: What is your goal here?

Comment: Just wanted to put commas between the values

Comment: It is still unclear why?  Are you trying to print the source?  Then use `prn` or `pprint`.  Are you trying to convert to strings? Then use `interpose` or similar. Your example sometimes implies you want strings, but when you mention macros it implies you want s-expressions (a data structure, very different from a string).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those characters all have special meaning in Clojure and you simply can not enter them just with the quote.  So they are handled with their meaning by the reader and then your `'` quote is used for the next form.  This all will lead to code that calls the one-arity version of `interpose`, which then will give you a transducer, thus resulting in the functions you see as results.

If you want to have those characters as symbols, you can use `symbol`.  E.g.

```clj
user=> (interpose (symbol ",") ["a" "b" "c"])
("a" , "b" , "c")
```

The meanings of those characters are:

- `,` is a [whitespace character](https://clojure.org/guides/weird_characters#_whitespace_character)
- `` ` `` and `~` are [syntax quote](https://clojure.org/guides/weird_characters#syntax_quote) and [unquote](https://clojure.org/guides/weird_characters#unqote) (mainly used in macros)

The resulting code with the unexpected behaviour looks basically like this then:

```clj
user=> `(interpose ', ["a" "b" "c"])
(clojure.core/interpose (quote ["a" "b" "c"]))
user=> `(interpose '` ["a" "b" "c"])
(clojure.core/interpose (quote (clojure.core/apply clojure.core/vector (clojure.core/seq (clojure.core/concat (clojure.core/list "a") (clojure.core/list "b") (clojure.core/list "c"))))))
user=> `(interpose '~ ["a" "b" "c"])
(clojure.core/interpose (quote ["a" "b" "c"]))
```

Comment: I'm a huge fan of Clojure macros, I thought ~ and ` are okay the act like that but comma confused me :)